# Low Search - Is it possible to do fulltext search on a channel entries comments?

Tags: low-search, comments

Using Low Search, is it possible to do fulltext search on a channel entries comments?

If so, then how? If not, are there any possible alternative actions one can do to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Low Search always returns **entries**. The search index used for the fulltext search is currently populated with entry data only.